# How to store conversation had with Alexa into database

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an Alexa skill for school, my client wants to store the conversation what Alexa had with parents and want to display it in the student's dashboard. How to store the whole conversation had with my skill into database?

Answer (score 1):

You **can get** and store/save what **alexa says** but you **can not** get exactly what the **user say** to alexa skill. But what you can get is user's intention (i.e what intent is called).
Solution to your problem is to use some database and make a table and do something like this in every intent

```js
const HelpIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
  
  
    const speechText = 'You can say hello to me!';
    *//write code to add speechText to a table against the intent name/sample utterence with date and time*
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**You will not get the skill user utterance** or what the user has said. But, with what you get from Alexa request, you can kind-of re-create the conversation flow.
Use these information:

1. **userId**
   If you don't have account linking in your skill, you will have to persist this to filter out conversations from a particular user. Please note that this `userId` will change when the user disable and re-enable your skill.
2. **sessionId**
   If you want to filter out a user's particular session. You can also depend on `SessionEndedRequest` to check know when the session ended, but this is clean.
3. **Intents**
   You wont get the user speech, but from `intents` you can identify the users intention. This will help you to guess what the user might have said.
4. **Slots**
   If you combine `slots` with the mapped `intents` you will get some more information. Since slot values are always passed to you, you can persist this and will know the exact value the user has said in his/her conversation.
5. **Timestamp**
   Always save the timestamp, this will help you to know when exactly the request came in.
6. **Alexa Response**
   Always persist the response you send back.
7. **sessionAttributes**
   If you have some cruicial information which you think will be helpful, then save it too.

With these information/filters if you sort it with `timestamp`,  you will get an idea about a particular/all user's conversation with Alexa.

Comment: can I get some example of how to do this?

Comment: Choose a database, and log these information from the request payload for every request. Once you have these records in your database, you can query it easily.

Comment: Sure I will try. Thank you